# trying to spice up a jquery ui accordion

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

[here's my current markup](http://jsbin.com/atibu/141/edit) (via JSBin).  i have a basic jquery ui accordion (i think everything is ok with it), but am looking to make it more visually appealing.

Basically, I'm trying to mirror the look and feel of *neon sky creative media's* flash-based menu, which i can't post a link to because new users can only post 1 hyperlink max.  just google "j-carrier photography" and you'll see an example of what I'm going for.

I've tried, and failed, to add a "+" icon (where applicable) on mouseover, and animate the background color and opacity of each menu item.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reference link: http://www.j-carrier.com/

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery ui css folder you will find the css file. It is commented extensively for easy editing. Most of what you want to do can be accomplished by editing this file.

See this site: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API for a complete reference.

Comment: yeah, im striking out with that too.  im just not sure how much of the base css to add.  i cant go with themeroller as i have no hosting priviledges for my site...strange i know.  the strange thing is i thought the jquery ui accordion contained icons by default...

Comment: UI does contain icons. These are in the css folder too.

Comment: so, if i understand you right, i should pull out the relevant css from the base stylesheet (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css).

Comment: i dont want to link the the stylesheet because my accordion is all set up, apart from the "+" and "-" icons.  when i link to it it applies a ton of stlyes to the accordion that i dont want.

Comment: would there be a way to just link to the actual icons, like through this link?

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png